# android - different layout editor?

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

I was trying to make an app with some fields that need user to fill out. I found this [image: pretty] which is exactly what I want, but when I copied over his code, I got this....[image: ugly]

I then realized that his project has different editor than mine. he has this 
[image: better] and i have this....
[image: bad]
does anyone know what's going on? how can he get this editor??

Comment: Don't simply rely on someone else's code to work for you. And I suggest learning to use the xml tab. You will learn more, have more flexibility, and your life will be a whole lot easier in the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the editor(layout designer), it's the sdks you have installed.

He's using 4.x or above. And yours is displaying pre-honeycomb Android 2.3.x or below.

On Windows, select **Window > SDK Managers**

Download and install `Android 4.3.x`. I've noticed that the layout designer in Eclipse displays the highest sdk installed by default (thought that can be changed through a pull-down menu).

If you run this code in an emulator, make sure the emulator you create supports the higher Android version number you've just downloaded (and change the target sdk in your manifest to the higher one). If you run this code on an actual phone that's 2.3.x or below, expect to see the old style just like you're seeing in your current editor.

Comment: I see....Can I change the target sdk to higher while editing my UI? then change back to lower sdk....because I want to support android 2.2